# Is this a bug of mathematica 8?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integrate

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Integrate[t f[x, y], {y, 0, 1}] - 
  t Integrate[f[x, y], {y, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify
```

Why doesn't M@ know the result is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug.  Since your `f[x,y]` has no definition, Mathematica can't assume anything about the integrand `t f[x, y]`

You can make a rule to help Mathematica as mentioned below. But without a rule, Mathematica is doing the right thing here.

This has been discussed many places before. Here are some links

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jsiYo9tRj04/rQYCy-X3SXQJ

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5610/how-to-simplify-symbolic-integration

For example, you can add this rule:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Integrate];
Integrate[t_Symbol*f_,dom_]:=t*Integrate[f,dom];
Protect[Integrate];
```

Now it will give zero

```
Simplify@Integrate[t f[x,y],{y,0,1}]-t Integrate[f[x,y],{y,0,1}]
(*--->  0 *)
```